# Ruby on Rails: Setting column variable from where query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Check in, check out methods in user model

```
def check_in(meeting)
  if meeting.nil?
    false
  elsif Attendance.where({user: self, meeting: meeting}).any?
    false
  else
    attendance = Attendance.create({user: self, meeting: meeting})
    attendance.in_time = Time.now
  end
end

def check_out(meeting)
  if meeting.nil?
    false
  else
    attendance = Attendance.where({user: self, meeting: meeting})
    attendance.present = true
    attendance.out_time = Time.now
  end  
end
```

rspec test for user model

```
describe 'check_out' do
  before(:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @meeting = FactoryGirl.create(:meeting)
    @user.check_in(@meeting)
    expect(@meeting.users).to include @user
    expect(@user.meetings).to include @meeting
  end

  it 'checks out the user' do
    expect(@user.check_out(@meeting)).to be_truthy
  end
end
```

Failure log

```
Failures:

1) User check_out checks out the user
   Failure/Error: expect(@user.check_out(@meeting)).to be_truthy
   NoMethodError:
   undefined method `present=' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
   # ./app/models/user.rb:84:in `check_out'
   # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:127:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have an attendance model with columns: id (int), user_id (int), meeting_id (int), in_time (time), out_time (time), present (boolean).

User has_many attendances and has_many meetings through attendances. 
Meeting has_many attendances and has_many users through attendances. 
Attendances belongs_to both user and meeting.

When the user checks in, it uses the check_in method and logs their time in. When they check_out, it runs the check_out method, which it confirms their attendance and logs their time out. The tests for check_in run flawlessly, but for check_out it fails?

My question is if there's an error in how I assign the where query to the variable (sorry for the terminology, I'm really new) and if I'm assigning the columns incorrectly (since it counts the column as a method?) If

I have no clue what's wrong and it would be great if somebody could help me out with this, thanks. :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is just that this line returns a collection of attendances instead of just one attendance:

```
attendance = Attendance.where({user: self, meeting: meeting})
```

You can simply add .first to end to have it grab the first one, like so:

```
attendance = Attendance.where({user: self, meeting: meeting}).first
```

or use the `find_by` method like so:

```
attendance = Attendance.find_by({user: self, meeting: meeting})
```

After that, you'll be calling `attendance.present = true` on an attendance object instead of a collection.